# Java/OO programming naming symbols?

Tags: java, oop, object, syntax, symbols

Reading through code written by multiple people in different countries using different languages I noticed that some use random symbols before the name of a constant:

The code is written like this:

```
int $temp = random(10)
doThing($temp);
$temp = 0;
```

Everywhere I see the symbol $ before a constant it refers to the constant being an integer.

So are there any other symbols people use to refer to different things?

I know that you cant name something like these items:

```
@item
&item
```

but you can do things like this:

```
person.get("car@speed");
person.get("car@cost");
```

do people use any other symbols for things?

Comment: Probably PHP devs. I didn't even know a variable name could start with a $ in Java.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yep, it's syntactically correct. Never seen it in practice.

Comment: @nicomp ["The dollar sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

Comment: [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) page lists the conventions for Java code, include variable names. As you can see it's archived and very old, but still applicable. It specifically discourages variable names starting with `$` or `_`, although "both are allowed".

Comment: "People" use a lot of different things. It's a whole different question whether or not it makes sense. Sticking to conventions is a very good idea if you want other people to be able to read through your code without wondering what's going on.

Comment: @AndyTurner source?

Comment: @nicomp why do you need another one?

Comment: @AndyTurner That's weird, my browser didn't render your comment as a link until now. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Each language has its peculiarities. Constants are usually in upper case, and variables begins with a letter. Depending on choosen convention, class members can begin with two underscore, and method argument with one underscore but it is up to you.
You should read code style best practices (there are a lot of resources on the internet)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the variables in the code snippet do not follow Java's naming conventions/standards.

Have a read of Java's documentation on variables. There is a section there about naming.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Hope this helps.